# Unable to connect via SSH: port 22 error

Tags: 13.10, ssh, macosx, openssh

I have two machines connected via the Ethernet cable. One machine is running Mac OS X , the other Ubuntu (13.10).

I am currently able to connect to the Mac via SSH. However when I try login in on the Ubuntu via SSH, I get the port 22 error. I can however connect to other machines from the Ubuntu.

I have Comcast. Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post the actual error message you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install openssh-server
 sudo ufw allow 22`

Run the commands listed above in the terminal. The first one will update the repository list. The second one will install openssh server and set up the default configuration. The third will allow connections to your computer over port 22.

This is just the bare minimum to connect to your computer using SSH. There are other things that you can do to secure your system from attack. Port 22 is well known for SSH and if you're allowing a connection to port 22 from the Internet you *will* see many people trying to attack it.

Comment: I performed the above commands. The output to the last comment is as follow:

Skipping adding existing rule
Skipping adding existing rule (v6)

Comment: I think that means ufw (iptables) is already allowing connections to port 22. It shouldn't be a problem. Have you tried connecting?

Comment: yes I tried connecting and still no success.

Comment: I was able to finally log on remotely after uninstalling NX NoMachine. I'm not sure why but it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the specific error message you get.

Is the ssh server running?  Verify by issuing this command:

```
service ssh status
```

Comment: I was able to finally log on remotely after uninstalling NX NoMachine. I'm not sure why but it finall works.

Answer (score 0):

On Centos 7 (I know, the problem's description is not for Centos, but it was the first google's search result) I had the `oppenssh-daemon` stopped:

I checked with

```
# service sshd status
```

Then I restarted it with:

```
# service sshd restart
```